# How to test an array object in phpunit?

Tags: php, arrays, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a static function is given below: want to test this function using PHPUnit

**One.php:**

```
static function myArray(myArrays $one) {
    $data = [
        "Name" => "name",
        "id" => "_id",
        "addressLine1" => "address1",
        "town" => "town",
        "district" => "district",
        "country" => "country",
        "mobile" => "mobile_number",
        "email" => "email",
        "url" => "_url"
    ];
    $output = [];

    foreach ($data as $myDatas => $value) {
        if ($one->truthy($myDatas)) {
            $field = $one->getField($myDatas);
            $output[$value] = $field; 
        }
    }
    $output['country'] = strtolower($oneninetwo->getField("countryCode", ""));


    return $output;
}
```

I have created a JSON file for this tests:

```
{ 
    "success":true,
    "data":{ 
       "id":"0001",
       "name":"Pizza",
       "addressLine1":"001 Down Town",
       "addressLine2":null,
       "addressLine3":null,
       "country":"AU",
       "countryCode":"au";
       "mobile":0123456789,
       "email":"test@test.com"
    }
 }
```

My tests:

```
public function testmyArray() {
    $mockreg = $this->getMockRegistry();

    $json = file_get_contents(__DIR__."/src/myjson.json");

    $data = json_decode($json, true);  

    $name = $data['data']['name'];
    $addressLine1 = $data['data']['addressLine1'];
    $addressLine2 = $data['data']['addressLine2'];
    $addressLine3 = $data['data']['addressLine3'];
    $mobile = $data['data']['mobile'];

    self::assertEquals($name, "Pizza");
    self::assertEquals($addressLine1, "001 Down Town");
    self::assertNull($addressLine2);
    self::assertTrue(is_numeric($mobile));


    $test = new class() extends One{ 
        function __construct() {
           $this->myArray();

           ----
        }
    };

}
```

Now want to tests the `One` class returns an array of objects with a value set and check the values?

Is this a good way to test or another way to test the array objects?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try avoid create more than one assertion per test case. Instead you can prepare expected array and compare with result for example if you have method:

```
public static function exampleMethod(): array
{
    // some logic

    return [
        'prop1' => 'Lorem ipsum',
        'prop_assoc' => [
            'dolor sit amet',
            'numeric_value' = 1
        ]
    ];
}
```

you can test it with following:

```
public function testExample(): void
{
    $expected = [
        'prop1' => 'Lorem ipsum',
        'prop_assoc' => [
            'dolor sit amet',
            'numeric_value' = 1
        ]
    ];

    $this->assertSame(ExampleClass::exampleMethod(), $expected);
}
```

Note: I've used [assertSame](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.0/assertions.html#assertsame) which check type and value, so there is no reason to use `is_numeric()`.

Comment: Can you please share an example with my tests? @user3545751

Comment: @Beniamin What is the Class contains adicional information not needed for the comparison of $expected?